# Recipient address required gmail api with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gmail-api

I'm trying to send a message with a jpeg file attached through the Gmail API in Javascript client side.
But I got error: Recipient address required. The code I've written so far is as follows:

```
SendMails() {
    var img=getBase64();
    const mails = [
      'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"\r\n',
      'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
      'to: limon14203165@gmail.com\r\n',
      'from: liibd7@gmail.com\r\n',
      'subject: Subject Text\r\n\r\n',

      '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
      'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n',
      'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n',

      'The actual message text goes here\r\n\r\n',

      '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
      'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n',
      'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n',
      'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.jpg"\r\n\r\n',

      img, '\r\n\r\n',

      '--foo_bar_baz--'
    ].join('');
    const path = 'upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart';
    const mail = btoa(mails).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');

    gapi.client.request({
      path: path,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'message/rfc822'
        // mimeType: 'message/rfc822'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        data: mail
      }
    }).then(response=> {
      console.log('Response:', response);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error:', err);
    });
  }
```

This results in an error response code 400, reason: "invalidArgument", message: "Recipient address required.
What am I doing wrong? It would be much appreciated if someone could shed some light on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your request body can be used. So how about this modification?

#### From:

```
const path = 'upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart';
const mail = btoa(mails).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');

gapi.client.request({
  path: path,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'message/rfc822'
    // mimeType: 'message/rfc822'
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    data: mail
  }
}).then(response=> {
  console.log('Response:', response);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error:', err);
});
```

#### To:

```
const path = 'upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send';  // Modified
// const mail = btoa(mails).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, ''); // Deleted
gapi.client.request({
  path: path,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'message/rfc822'},
  method: 'POST',
  body: mails  // Modified
}).then(response=> {
  console.log('Response:', response);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error:', err);
});
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your `gapi.client` can be used for sending a message using Gmail API.

#### References:

- [gapi.client.request(args)](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md#api-requests)
- [Users.messages: send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)